# How to Plot 2 classification report result in one graph in python

Tags: python, plot, classification, precision-recall

I have two classification report results (from 2 different models), and I want to use a bar chart to plot them in one single graph. How can I do this?

Sample classificaiotn report result:

```
             precision  recall   f1-score  support

   False       0.94      0.95     0.95     10078
   True        0.95      0.94     0.94     10078

accuracy                          0.94     20156
macro avg      0.94      0.94     0.94     20156
weighted avg   0.94      0.94     0.94     20156
```